# mysqldump bash script stopping at password "command not found"

Tags: bash, ssh, mysql

Whenever I try to run the bash script, its taking my password as a command. I am receiving "command not found" at the password portion. If use -p in the script, it accepts it in the prompt, but not when the password is in the script.

How would I go about "escaping" the password so its taken as plain text and not a command?

I tried password="thepassword" and $password, etc, no avail

```
 #!/bin/bash
 date=`date +%A`

 mysqldump --opt -Q -u somedb -somecrazypassword usersomedb > /backup/backup-$date.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot `-p` before like `-psomecrazypassword`